# libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies

Tags: linux, qt, fedora, cgal

I'm installing *CGAL 4.13* on Fedora but it cannot generate `libCGAL_Qt5.so`

```
Configuring libCGAL_Qt5
libCGAL_Qt5 is missing the dependencies: Qt5OpenGL Qt5Svg Qt5 cannot be configured.
```

[image: lib folder screenshot]

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [CGAL_Installation_Guide_V2.1.pdf](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxzaW5naHN1a2hyYWp8Z3g6MThiNjRkNjhhMWY0ZjgyYw) can help you, its said about installing `CGAL` and dependencies. Just do step by step.

Comment: thanks for the great tutorial , I followed your steps but I'm having a few problems : 
- when I try "sudo apt-get update" it shows sudo apt-get update
- when I press configure using cmake it shows "Qt5Svg-dir-not-found" I try to set it manually to" /usr/lib64/cmake" the same problem still found

Comment: You have using fedora distribution, so instead `sudo apt-get update` see below link how `sudo-apt update` does work in fedora  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367872/what-is-the-similar-command-of-ubuntus-sudo-apt-get-update-in-fedora

Comment: the problem is solved by installing qt5-devel from dnf (fedora package manager)
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev`